UPS Rating API Getting Invalid Weight Error
I am trying to integrate UPS RATING API and getting error message below:

{"response":{"errors":[{"code":"110601","message":"Missing or invalid package weight for package 1."}]}}

This is my JSON request:
{
    "RateRequest": {
      "Request": {
        "TransactionReference": {
          "CustomerContext": "CustomerContext"
        }
      },
      "Shipment": {
        "Shipper": {
          "Name": "ShipperName",
          "ShipperNumber": "123456",
          "Address": {
            "AddressLine": [
              "ShipperAddressLine",
              "ShipperAddressLine",
              "ShipperAddressLine"
            ],
            "City": "TIMONIUM",
            "StateProvinceCode": "MD",
            "PostalCode": "21093",
            "CountryCode": "US"
          }
        },
        "ShipTo": {
          "Name": "ShipToName",
          "Address": {
            "AddressLine": [
              "ShipToAddressLine",
              "ShipToAddressLine",
              "ShipToAddressLine"
            ],
            "City": "Alpharetta",
            "StateProvinceCode": "GA",
            "PostalCode": "30005",
            "CountryCode": "US"
          }
        },
        "ShipFrom": {
          "Name": "ShipFromName",
          "Address": {
            "AddressLine": [
              "ShipFromAddressLine",
              "ShipFromAddressLine",
              "ShipFromAddressLine"
            ],
            "City": "TIMONIUM",
            "StateProvinceCode": "MD",
            "PostalCode": "21093",
            "CountryCode": "US"
          }
        },
        "PaymentDetails": {
          "ShipmentCharge": {
            "Type": "01",
            "BillShipper": {
              "AccountNumber": "123456"
            }
          }
        },
        "Service": {
          "Code": "03",
          "Description": "Ground"
        },
        "NumOfPieces": "1",
        "Package": {
          "SimpleRate": {
            "Description": "SimpleRateDescription",
            "Code": "XS"
          },
          "PackagingType": {
            "Code": "02",
            "Description": "Packaging"
          },
          "Dimensions": {
            "UnitOfMeasurement": {
              "Code": "IN",
              "Description": "Inches"
            },
            "Length": "5",
            "Width": "5",
            "Height": "5"
          },
          "PackageWeight": {
            "UnitOfMeasurement": {
              "Code": "LBS",
              "Description": "Pounds"
            },
            "Weight": "5"
          },
          "ShipmentTotalWeight": {
            "UnitOfMeasurement": {
              "Code": "LBS",
              "Description": "Pounds"
            },
            "Weight": "5"
          }    
        }
      }
    }
  }

According to their documentation my JSON is formatted as expected but it is not reading the weight for some reason.
I must be missing something but can't see what.
Any help would be appreciated.

Why are all your numeric values in quotes? Could it be that the api is interpreting them as strings instead of numbers? Have you tried sending numbers? Just riffing out here.

They are supposed to be strings according to their documentation.

Can you ls include a link to the docs you are citing in your question

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

I think there is an array missing in the JSON request.
The package weight should be inside of the package array where package is an object.
"Package": [
            {
                "SimpleRate": {
                    "Description": "SimpleRateDescription",
                    "Code": "XS"
                },
                "PackagingType": {
                    "Code": "02",
                    "Description": "Packaging"
                },
                "Dimensions": {
                    "UnitOfMeasurement": {
                        "Code": "IN",
                        "Description": "Inches"
                    },
                    "Length": "5",
                    "Width": "5",
                    "Height": "5"
                },
                "PackageWeight": {
                    "UnitOfMeasurement": {
                        "Code": "LBS",
                        "Description": "Pounds"
                    },
                    "Weight": "5"
                }
            }
        ]

So, package is an object. Can you try it like this? It worked for me.
